# CentOS: SIOCGMIIREG on eth0

Tags: ubuntu, centos

What does SIOCGMIIREG on eth0 failed error mean? This is causing our POS network down.

ifconfig:

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr  00:215E:6A:FF:64
    inet addr:10.100.202.254  Bcast:10.100.255.255 Mask:255.255.0.0
    inet6 addr: fe80::221:5eff:fe6a:ff64/64 Scope:Link
    UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
    RX packets:5150398 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:5759767 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000RX bytes:446687229 (425.9 MiB)
    TX bytes 411178218 (392.1 MiB)
    Memory:91a80000-91aa0000
```

lo  Link encap:Local Loopback
    inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
    inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
    UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436  Metric:1
    RX packets:1922985 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:1922985 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
    RX bytes:490439549 (467.7 MiB)  TX bytes 490439549 (467.7 MiB)

mii-diag:

```
Using the default interface 'eth0'
SIOCGMIIREC on eth-0 failed: Input/output error
```

NOW DOING: cat /etc/*release*
NOW DOING: network (netstat -apn)
NOW DOING: arp (arp -a)
NOW DOING: sar (static)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full error you are getting. Also, what network card and driver are you using? You tagged your question with Ubuntu and centos. Which one is it? What OS version?

Comment: Hi Erika. Our OS is CentOS 5.2 in some sites, while it's 5.4 in the other sites.  our POS workstations' lan card is EEPRO100 autodetect.  Our server's driver is e1000.  Normally, in one of the problematic sites, POS and EFT share in one mini hub of 10mbps while the others in a 5 port mini switch with 100mbps.  speed and duplex are set to auto.  during pinging, latency is very low that's why we are puzzled why we encounter broken services and network down.

Answer (score 0):

It likely means that your network card's driver doesn't support whatever it is that you're asking it to do. Seen often when using `mii-tool` when you should be using `ethtool`.

Comment: Hi Erika. Our OS is CentOS 5.2 in some sites, while it's 5.4 in the other sites.  our POS workstations' lan card is EEPRO100 autodetect.  Our server's driver is e1000.  Normally, in one of the problematic sites, POS and EFT share in one mini hub of 10mbps while the others in a 5 port mini switch with 100mbps.  speed and duplex are set to auto.  during pinging, latency is very low that's why we are puzzled why we encounter broken services and network down.

Comment: Hi. Our OS is CentOS 5.2 in some sites, while it's 5.4 in the other sites.  our POS workstations' lan card is EEPRO100 autodetect.  Our server's driver is e1000.  Normally, in one of the problematic sites, POS and EFT share in one mini hub of 10mbps while the others in a 5 port mini switch with 100mbps.  speed and duplex are set to auto.  during pinging, latency is very low that's why we are puzzled why we encounter broken services and network down.

Comment: Hi Wes, please check out the exact result of ifconfig and the error message encountered in my response to erika